# "I will be" versus "I would have"

Tags: tense, phrases, phrase-choice

Which one is correct to state?

> At the end of the year I will be graduating from college.

> At the end of the year I would have graduated from college.

Comment: If you change #2 from _would have_ to _will have_, then you can say either one. (I think #2 is grammatical, but it doesn't sound natural to me.)

Comment: Whereas _At the end of LAST year I would have graduated, if only..._

Comment: @J.R. #2 is grammatical but probably doesn't mean what OP wants it to; for example, *At the end of the year I would have graduated from college if I had taken 4 extra credits.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most contexts, you definitely want to use:

> At the end of the year I will be graduating from college

The time is in the future, so the event is going to happen.

Additionally, 'would have' conveys an exceptional occurrence, eg, 'I would have woken earlier, but my alarm wasn't working this morning'.

There *are* circumstances where you could be talking about future events as though they were in the past, and in this situation you could use the second format.  For example, a local anti drink-driving ad campaign was providing comparisons of a person who either chose to drive under the influence, or take a taxi home.  In this case they used examples in the nature of:

> If John hadn't chosen to drive home drunk, at the end of the year he would have graduated from college, in three years he would have married his high school sweetheart, etc.

This is more contrived than the first usage, but is still correct.